# JQuery Vegas Overlay pattern wont display

Tags: jquery-plugins, overlay

I'm new to the vegas plug-in. I think I've followed the directions correctly.
My script in the :

```
$.vegas('slideshow', {
  delay:5000,
  backgrounds:[
    { src:'img/dark1-500.jpg', fade:1500 },
    { src:'img/dark2-500.jpg', fade:1500 },
    { src:'img/dark3-500.jpg', fade:1500 },
    { src:'img/dark4-500.jpg', fade:1500 },
    ]
    })('overlay', {
      src:'img/01.png',
      opacity:0.5
});
```

I also have this in CSS:

```
.vegas-overlay {
   background:transparent url(img/01.png); 
   opacity:0.5;
   z-index:-1; 
}
```

Do both overlay declarations need to be there? Is one stepping on the other?

Thanks for any help.
J

Comment: I figured this out. Just one image declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by deleting one and then the other declaration.